# Would it be petty of me to make the use of full plate armor a war crime?

Tags: warfare, combat, armors

Now this goes back to another question I asked a while back and i will openly admit this is more out of spite than anything else, but I just hear people going on and on about how full plate is the pinnacle of medieval technology, makes the user borderline invincible and allows them to run rampant(or so people claim as there are ways to beat someone in plate armor but that's not the point.)

So, I'm thinking "Ok. If people seem to think plate armor is so much better than anything else assuming you can afford it, why not just make it illegal?" The justification being unlike most weapons and armor which you could reasonably argue would be carried and used for self-defense purposes, plate armor is so hyper optimized for warfare that the only reason anybody would utilize it is if they had the intention to attack or invade unprovoked.

Now obviously there are a lot more nuances to this, but I've gotten so fed up with people taking about how unbeatable full plate armor is, that I'm tempted to just say "Screw it, let's make it illegal to use." As just removing it from the equation entirely would solve a lot of problems.

Comment: You do realize that the very *idea* of a war crime only came up **after** the Crimean War, aka WW0, hundreds of years after the full plate was dropped as useless?

Comment: What's the question here? Are you asking how the populace is going to *perceive* such a law?

Comment: How would the ban be enforced? What if neighboring countries don't follow the suit? What if a country far away beyond other countries' borders don't? You will be a sitting duck unless you can do it efficiently and reliably everywhere where there are potential enemies, which would be quite a feat.

Comment: I'm more asking if I would be thought of as spiteful for making it illegal in said setting, just to give a middle finger to people who lawd over it so much. And I'm no fool enough to think this could be enforced everywhere, just the places that don't listen would be considered antagonistic and if they do decide to ignore the ban they better make sure they win or else the punishment is severe.

Comment: What, is this some meta commentary towards people that think plate armour is awesome? Why makes you think they will read your work and have such an averse reaction to that, that you must ask for advice about going too far? If so, two things: 1) people are a lot less sensitive than some like to claim... the claim that people taking offense at everything is just martyr-mentality, when in fact almost no-on cares 2) offense is not given it is taken. If you are hoping that someone will take offense at your fictional concept of making plate armor a war crime... eh, good luck with that.

Comment: I just grew frustrated scouring the Internet for strategies, blade designs, anything to show it's not this insernountable wall only hindered by cost, just to be met with the same people going "Nope only full plate can beat full plate" because people seem to naturally gravitate towards anything that requires the least amount of thinking to use.

Comment: VTC:Not About WB per the [help] (a) Per the [help], we're here to help you build an imaginary world. Per the [tour] we don't host discussions. (b) Believe me, it's not our job to judge whether or not anything you do is petty. (c) While it might be interesting to help you develop a rule for your imaginary world where a treaty exists that bans the use of plate mail (not unlike treaties that ban the use of chemical weapons...), simply asking for comments about a concept violates the [help/dont-ask] prohibition against questions being "just a rant in disguise."

Comment: @Masakan that's probably because you don't understand how plate armor developed, and why - and then don't see that this directly led to the development other weapons that were designed to pierce it. The Raven's beak and pole axe were direct responses to the growth of armor thickness, which lead to armor getting thicker and even more armor breaching weapons. Armor ultimately lost the development to gunpowder weapons and was phased out. Even before gunpowder led to abolishment of all armor, the solution was often enough an **all or nothing** scheme, such as a very heavy cuirass and nothing else.

Comment: To be honest I probably wouldn't get so upset if it didn't feel like this is a universally accepted belief in a good chunk of HEMA circles, along with the idea that "the spear/stick is the king of all weapons" I know I shouldn't care but like you said it's very short sighted and people taking such pride in being so short sighted will never not bother me. But you're right, I really shouldn't let this get to me.

Comment: @Masakan Maybe you should try to look at why people deem spears superior and when - Because spears and glaives and halberds gain their high regard from being dirt cheap, providing reach, and being super easy to learn some effectivity with. all but the price they have in common with firearms.

Answer (score 2):

Full plate is not the superweapon it seems to be, which solves your problem.

- Full plate is expensive. Making it takes the labor of specialized artisans and raw materials. So no country will be able to equip their peasant levies with it, or even the personal retainers of most nobles. Either full plate is for *knights* only, or full plate is for a few *elite regiments* of the monarch.
- Full plate requires logistics support. Soldiers cannot march in full armor and then fight. For every armored soldier, you need squires, grooms, pack horses, etc. Again, this limits the widespread employment.

On top of that, most societies which might have considered plate armor had heavy **class or caste** distinctions. In many cases, the nobles would not even speak the same language as their peasants. They were socially closer to nobles in other countries than to their own commoners.

**So make it a crime for commoners to wear full plate.** Why, they could get ideas above their station! Barons can wear full plate, knights can wear half plate, personal retainers can wear mail and/or breast plates. Commoners get leather or quilted cloth.